# Making a Page Inaccessible With a Button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is something similar to what YouTube has when you click their menu icon; the rest of the page gets darker and nothing on that part of the page is accessible to the user until the button is clicked again and the menu recedes. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body lang = 'en-US'>
<head>
    <meta charset = 'UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv = 'X-UA-Compatible' content = 'IE = edge'>
    <meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1'>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <!-- links to relative files -->
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = '/Custom_Scrollbar.CSS'>
    <link rel = 'shortcut icon' type = 'image/png' href = '/Images/Odd_Jobs_Favicon.png'>
</head>


<body>
    <div class = 'headerBar'>
        <style>
            .headerBar {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 80px;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background-color: #e0e0e0;
            }
        </style>
    </div>

    <div class = 'headerStrip'>
        <style>
            .headerStrip {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 5px;
                top: 80px;
                left: 0px;
                background-color: #5e00bc
            }
        </style>
    </div>

    <div class = 'bodyBar'>
        <style>
            .bodyBar {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 85px;
                left: 0px;
                background-color: #000000
            }
        </style>
    </div>


     <div class = 'jobLinks'>
        <li><a class = 'find' href = '#'>Link</a></li>
        <style>
             .jobLinks {
                text-decoration: none;
                list-style: none;
            }
        
            .find {
                position: absolute;
                width: 80px;
                height: 40px;
                top: 30px;
                left: 300px;
                font-family: 'comfortaa';
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: 800;
                color: #000000;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-align: center;
                transition: ease-out 0.4s;
                background-color: #e0e0e0;
            }
        
            .find:hover {
                color: #5e00bc;
            }
        </style>
    </div>

    <div class = 'menu'>
        <button class = 'menuButton'></button>
        <div class = 'linkList'>
            <ul>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 6</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <style>
            .menuButton {
                position: absolute;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                top: 25px;
                left: 1303px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                transition: ease-out 0.5s;
                background-image: url('/Images/Menu_Icon.png');
                background-color: #e0e0e0;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .links {
                font-family: 'comfortaa';
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: 500;
                color: #000000;
                text-decoration: none;
                transition: ease-out 0.4s;
            }

            .links:hover {
                color: #5e00bc;
            }

            .linkList {
                position: fixed;
                width: 150px;
                height: 100%;
                right: -150px;
                top: 85px;
                transition: ease-out 0.5s;
                background: #e0e0e0;
            }

            .linkList ul li {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 15px;
            }

            .menuButton:focus ~ .linkList {
                right: 0px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            menuBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('menuButton')[0];
            menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                menu = document.getElementsByClassName('linkList')[0];
                menu.style.webkitTransition = '0.6s';
                if (menu.style.right == '0px') {
                    menu.style.right = '-150px';
                } else {
                menu.style.right = '0px';
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an alterative, [Bootstrap Offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#live-demo) does all this without having to write and maintain custom css and js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It can be achieved by some `css` and `js`.
- I am adding `menuOpen` class when the menu is open. and removing it when the menu is closed.
- `menuOpen` class `css` is setting other content besides menu unaccesseiable.

```js
const open = document.querySelector("#open");
const close = document.querySelector("#close");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

open.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.add("active");
  document.body.classList.add("menuOpen");
});
close.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.remove("active");
  document.body.classList.remove("menuOpen");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: .5s;
}

#menu.active {
  left: 0;
}

.menuOpen {
  position: relaive;
  transition: .5s;
}

.menuOpen::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="open">open</button>
<div id="menu">
  <button id="close">close</button>
  <button>a</button>
  <button>a</button>
  <button>a</button>
</div>
<p>content</p>
```